# How to create a SQLite database UWP

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, win-universal-app

I'm new in creating Data Bases and I should to create a SQLite DB, which contains Buses, every Bus contains a list of Stops and every Stop contains a timetable. I have create a class Buses:

```
class Buses
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public string number { get; set; }
    public List<Stop> stops = new List<Stop>();
}

 public class Stop
{
    public string StopName { get; set; }
    public string Timetable { get; set; }
}
```

And I don't know how should I add stops to the DB. I trying something like this:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = conn.Insert(new Buses()
        {
            number = Id.Text,
            stops = stops.Add(new Stop { StopName = StopName.Text, Timetable = Time.Text });
 }
```

But I get error

> The name 'stops' does not exist in the current context

I understand, why there such error is, but I don't know, how to fix it. It is possible, that there are easiest ways to adding such constructions to the DB.

Comment: You need to define a list of Stop called `stops` like `List<Stop> stops = new List<Stop>`.

Comment: Where I should do it? At the class Buses I have the same

Comment: For example before the `Add_Click` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm new in creating Data Bases and I should to create a SQLite DB, which contains Buses, every Bus contains a list of Stops and every Stop contains a timetable.

You cannot create a table with a column to **store a list of object** in SQLite. Because there is no such [datatype supported in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). So the Buses table you have created will never store its stop list into SQLite.

Based on my understanding, a bus can have many stops, and a stop is also used for many buses, the relationship between bus and stop should be **Many-to-Many**. So you may need to create another **relationship table** in addition to **table Buses** and **table Stop**.  As both table Buses and table Stop are very simple in your scenario, I just create **one relationship table** here (it makes it simpler and also works but may cause redundancy):

```
class Buses
{
    public string number { get; set; }

    public string StopName { get; set; }

    public string Timetable { get; set; }
}
```

Use the following code to **add the stop**:

```
    private async void btnAddStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // check if the stop is already added for the bus
        List<Buses> buses = new List<Buses>();
        buses = LocalDatabase.GetStopListByBusNumberAndStopName(Id.Text, StopName.Text);
        if (buses.ToArray().Length > 0)
        {
            await new MessageDialog("Cannot add this stop because the stop is already added for the bus!").ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            Buses b = new Buses();
            b.number = Id.Text;
            b.StopName = StopName.Text;
            b.Timetable = Timetable.Text;
            // add the stop to db
            LocalDatabase.InsertStopToDatabase(b);
            await new MessageDialog("The stop is added successfully!").ShowAsync();
        }
    }

    // get the buses by bus number
    public static List<Buses> GetStopListByBusNumber(string busNumber)
    {
        List<Buses> results = new List<Buses>();
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath))
        {
            results = conn.Query<Buses>("SELECT * FROM Buses WHERE number = ?", busNumber);
        }
        return results;
    }

    // get the buses by bus number and stop name
    public static List<Buses> GetStopListByBusNumberAndStopName(string busNumber, string stopName)
    {
        List<Buses> results = new List<Buses>();
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath))
        {
            results = conn.Query<Buses>("SELECT * FROM Buses WHERE number = ? AND StopName = ?", busNumber, stopName);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Then use the following code to **retrieve the stop list for a bus**:

```
    // get the buses by bus number
    public static List<Buses> GetStopListByBusNumber(string busNumber)
    {
        List<Buses> results = new List<Buses>();
        using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath))
        {
            results = conn.Query<Buses>("SELECT * FROM Buses WHERE number = ?", busNumber);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Here is the [entire sample](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E754412D31A2DF3D!109&authkey=!AJ8Cs6PzgZtIFYo&ithint=file%2czip) for your reference.

Comment: An I have one more question: is it possible to get created DB, for using it at another projects?

Comment: Yes, we can do that. You can find the created DB file through the DBPath(For the sample it is:  C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Packages\4acb2c95-231a-4076-8d1c-b692f3b0660b_nj3bh83vzc3v4\LocalState\BusAndStops.sqlite). The two projects can even share the same DB if you put the DB file into a special folder that both projects can access.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way fast object initializes work in .Net

```
var s = conn.Insert(new Buses()
    {
        number = Id.Text,
        stops = stops.Add(new Stop { StopName = StopName.Text, Timetable = Time.Text });
    }
```

Inside the initialize block - You cannot get the values your other members.

(Even if you could get the member value, the function stops.Add is void - which does not return a new list)

If you want to use the quick initialize way:

```
var s = conn.Insert(new Buses()
{
    number = Id.Text,
    stops = new List<Stop>() 
    {
        new Stop { StopName = StopName.Text, Timetable = Time.Text }),
    }
}
```

Or you can do it without:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bus = new Buses()
    {
        number = Id.Text,
    };
    bas.stops.Add(new Stop { StopName = StopName.Text, Timetable = Time.Text });
    var s = conn.Insert(bus);
}
```